# Issue while running rabbitMQ docker image on windows 8 with volume for retaining the container data

Tags: windows, docker, rabbitmq

I'm trying to run the rabbitMQ docker image on my windows 8, using volume flag to retain the container data

`docker pull rabbitmq:management`

`docker run --name rabbitmq-mgmt --detach --publish 15672:15672 --publish 5672:5672 --hostname my-rabbit-mgmt --volume $HOME/docker/volumes/rabbitmq/data:/var/lib/rabbitmq --volume $HOME/docker/volumes/rabbitmq/logs:/var/log/rabbitmq rabbitmq:management`

with the above command, I get this error

**"Cookie file /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie must be accessible by owner only"**

tried to find the solution for this googling and found suggestion of changing the volume folder to /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia instead of /var/lib/rabbitmq

`docker run --name rabbitmq-mgmt --detach --publish 15672:15672 --publish 5672:5672 --hostname my-rabbit-mgmt --volume $HOME/docker/volumes/rabbitmq/data:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia --volume $HOME/docker/volumes/rabbitmq/logs:/var/log/rabbitmq rabbitmq:management`

but with this is also failing with this error

**init terminating in do_boot ({error,{could_not_write_file,/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@my-rabbit-mgmt/cluster_nodes.config,etxtbsy}})**

When checked the user/group for the folder mnesai inside container, it's not rabbitmq:rabbitmq, it looks this is the issue. Not sure how to change this

`drwxr-xr-x 2 rabbitmq rabbitmq 4096 Nov 19 19:50 schema`

`drwxr-xr-x 3 rabbitmq rabbitmq 4096 Nov 20 09:24 config`

`drwxrwxrwx 1     1000 staff    4096 Nov 20 09:24 mnesia`

could someone please help here?

Comment: It looks like some access issues with the local host drive which has been mounted in the docker image.. Make sure that that folder is shared through the docker for windows control panel

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee, the folder is shared properly, it's the default user directory in the windows. Other containers like jenkins, works fine with the same shared folder.

Comment: Try this docker run --name rabbitmq-mgmt --detach --publish 15672:15672 --publish 5672:5672 --hostname my-rabbit-mgmt --volume $HOME/docker/volumes/rabbitmq/data:/var/lib/rabbitmq --volume $HOME/docker/volumes/rabbitmq/logs:/var/log/rabbitmq -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='secret cookie here'  rabbitmq:management

Comment: it doesn't work, still same issue. If you see the latest update, issues seems to be with this  ```drwxrwxrwx 1     1000 staff    4096 Nov 20 09:24 mnesia```. any idea how to change the user/group here to rabbitmq:rabbitmq instead of 1000:staff?

Comment: No bro... can't you move away from Windows 8...